# Android 2.0 App not available on 2.2 devices

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

Has anyone seen that their applications built against Android 2.0 (`minSdkVersion="5"`) are not showing up at all in the market for 2.2 devices? Does anyone know a workaround (aside from building for 2.2).

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: My app doesn't show up as well. It's minSdkVersion="3", but built with Android 2.2.

Comment: My app has minSdkVersion="4" built using 1.6 and my users are reporting that they can't see my app in the market.

Comment: Check out Google's comments on this. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/application-visibility-issues.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good explanation of why this is happening:

"When an app is copy protected it causes this kind of behavior. Here is why. When an app is placed on the market the developer has the option to apply “Forward Locking”. This prevents the app from being pirated, and also prevents the app from being installed on a developer phone or an unreleased device.

Since Android 2.2 is not an “official” release yet the market gets a little unhappy because it doesn’t know what this OS/Device is that is trying to connect and thus applies the copy protection on these apps."

http://androidheadlines.com/2010/06/froyo-preventing-access-to-certain-apps-in-the-market.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that protected and some paid app are not showing in 2.2

See Paul (ModaCo) twitter:

"It's entirely possible Google haven't 'flicked the switch' on the FRF50 build.prop yet, hence no paid apps until they do!"

edit: and I guess that protected app's are linked too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a signature key for each Android build out there, including each manufacturer's inclusion of it in a device.

When you access the market, it checks this signature to see which applications you have permission to view.

In this case, Google have probably not enabled that signature to see certain applications, such as apps which are paid, protected or perhaps built for certain versions.

They still haven't enabled HTC Desire to view protected apps and it has been out for nearly two months -- there's even a bit of a furore over it on the internet, but Google don't seem to mind.